# Using POI4XPages SVE control and browser window closed before completing download

Tags: apache-poi, xpages, xpages-ssjs

If the browser window/tab closes before the download of the export finishes, the HTTP service appears to be locked up. But only for the application I am running the poi4xpages process in. Any idea how to prevent this? I can imagine users doing this and a restart of http service every time is not an optimal solution.

Comment: You can't control the user, but you can control your code. I would double check your code to make sure it has adequate error handling.  Use Try/Catch blocks (even in SSJS) to trap the error, and a Finally statement that always runs to attempt to clean up the processes that cause HTTP to lock up. Good luck!

Comment: I have never experienced an issue with the browser window/tab closing before the process finished.  However, if you are referring to the user as Steve has pointed out that is a different ball game.  Post your concern on the project site and you will get a response from the developer who is very responsive.  If you had posted previously follow-up because I know he was out with an illness for quite some time.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen threads locked up like this - though I'm NOT an admin.  They can get locked up I believe if the users clicks the "download" button more then once.  I think there's a couple solutions but I typically have the button open a new Page/Tab that calls the XAgent that triggers the download.